# Sails.js create Index(root) Controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I was wondering if there is a way to have an index controller with an index action. my root is a login page and I wanted to detect if the users session is already authenticated and if so redirect them to another page.

Is there specific notation for how the controller is named? I have already tried IndexController.js and MainController.js. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about this.

Sails.js Ver: 0.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the controller and action yourself. From there, set up a [Policy](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) to define access.

To make the controller, run `sails generate controller Index` in console.

Then, open **api/controllers/IndexController.js**, make it look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function (req, res) {
    // add code to display logged in view
  }
};
```

Set up **config/routes.js** to look like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  'get /': 'IndexController.index',
};
```

Afterwards, define a policy which has your authentication logic. Alternatively, you can use the included session authentication located at **api/policies/sessionAuth.js** assuming that your login action sets `req.session.authenticated = true;`. See [the docs on policies](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) for more info.

Lastly, connect the policy to the action in **config/policies.js**:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  IndexController: {
    '*': false,                  // set as default for IndexController actions
    index: 'sessionAuth'         // or the name of your custom policy
  }
}
```