# How to design a secure web architecture for login using session in sails.js

Tags: javascript, session, web, sails.js

I want to design a secure web architecture for login using session in sails.js.

I have roles and permission as well after login process.

Any answer ( GUI/ Diagram ) will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cover these cases pretty well using Sails.js Policies. [Here are the docs.](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) You can have a one for authentication and create additional ones based on what roles you have.

To get started with a basic authenticated view, I wrote a quick guide in the answer to another question here: [Sails.js create Index(root) Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040634/sails-js-create-indexroot-controller)

Comment: Hey cheniel, can you please provide me an architecture for the same. I know these policies and controller process. My question is for web architecture not for implementation part. I asked a diagram for the same.

Comment: You're going to need to spec out a lot more in your question before someone can make that